# Are these results reliable to make sure that there is a root in FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I want to use FindRoot for a 3-variable equation to make sure if there is a root around the point $\{x,2.356\},\{y,0.2\},\{z,0.802\}$

```
f := 16 ((-1 + x^2) Cos[z] Cosh[2.941592653589793` x] + 
      2 x Sin[z] Sinh[2.941592653589793` x]) Sinh[π x] + 
   8 (-1 + x^2) Sinh[x y] + (-3 + x^2)^2 Sinh[
     x (2 π + y)] - (1 + 
      x^2)^2 (2 Cosh[5.883185307179586` x] Sinh[x y] + 
      Sinh[2 π x - x y]);
der = D[f, {{x, y, z}}];

FindRoot[der == {0, 0, 0}, {{x, 2.356}, {y, 0.2}, {z, 0.802}}];
res = {x, y, z} /. %
f /. %%
```

The result is

> {2.35652, 0.2, 0.802647}

> -1.49012*10^-8

Then, when I increase working precision, I get

```
FindRoot[der == {0, 0, 0}, {{x, 2.356}, {y, 0.2}, {z, 0.802}}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 32];
res = {x, y, z} /. %
f /. %%
```

> During evaluation of In[134]:= FindRoot::precw: The precision of the argument function ({<<1>>}=={0,0,0}) is less than WorkingPrecision (32.`). >>

> {2.3565200441011191861934980908179, 
> 0.20000007532203647354553006825369, 0.80264668264222070286493054169596}

> 0. 

Then, does this mean that there is a root at this point? In general, when without increasing precision I get the result $-\text{1.4901161193847656$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8}$, does this show that there is a root there? Or, the result must be exactly zero?

Comment: With machine precision numbers you will never get exactly 0. You will always get a small error. If you want accurate calculations, you need to use rational numbers. Of course, this may take much longer.

Comment: If a continuous function crosses from negative to positive then there must be a root. If you redefine `f` as a function `f[x_,y_,z_] :=...;` and apply `f @@@ RandomPoint[Sphere[{2.35652, 0.2, 0.802647}, 10^-5], 100]` you see both negative and positive values meaning it must equal exactly zero in the vicinity of your approximate root.

Comment: @flinty Therefore, you agree that there is a root in this neighborhood?

Comment: @charmin yes that much is clear and Ulrich's answer shows there are in fact many roots at all points along the contours shown. The only concern I have is whether those contours connect at a point, and plotting would not be adequate to show this. Have a look at the gradient nearby - it's close to zero. `Norm[Grad[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]] /. {x -> 
   2.3565200441011191861934980908179, 
  y -> 0.200000075322036473545530068253690, 
  z -> 0.80264668264222070286493054169596}`. Unfortunately I don't know how to prove they are connected or otherwise.

Comment: Because of round-off error in floating-point computations of the value of `f[]`, you can only be confident there is (probably) a root, but never completely sure.  In fact, given the round-off error in the coefficients of `f`, the function `f` and its derivative probably do not simultaneously vanish exactly.  They appear very close to doing so, though.  I would say it's close enough, but whether one should accept it really depends on how the result is being used. I would accept it because the problem as posed is approximate and I wouldn't insist on exact answers.

Comment: @charmin: Why don't you tell the whole story? Why you concealed the exact expressions of numeric constants? `N[\[Pi] - 1/5, 16] == 2.941592653589793`
`N[2 (\[Pi] - 1/5), 16] == 5.883185307179586`

Comment: @azerbajdzan Sorry, I do not understand what you mean? What I concealed? This is the whole question I had in my mind.

Comment: @charmin: Where did the equations come from? Your constants `2.941592653589793 = π-1/5` and `5.883185307179586 = 2*(π - 1/5)` it cannot be a coincidence.

Comment: @azerbajdzan That is true. You are right. It was my bad and carelessness in simplifying the final equation. I just wanted to have a general idea about these kinds of problems. Since this equation is a part of another long equation, and I just chose some random variables and simplified its different expressions separately and then, put them together.  But does this affect the result?

Comment: Of course it does effect the result. If you replace exact numbers with rounded then the location of the root is shifted or in extreme situations the root can disappear.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Thank you very much. I will check my case using the methods suggested.

Comment: According to your code, you want to know if `f == 0` when the derivative vanishes.  You accepted an answer that does not deal with that. (-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use higher precision, you must start with higher precision, preferably exact numbers. So, define:

```
rf = Rationalize[f, 0];
der = D[rf, {{x, y, z}}]
```

> {8 (-1 + x^2) y Cosh[x y] + (-3 + x^2)^2 (2 π + y) Cosh[
> x (2 π + y)] +
> 16 [Pi] Cosh[π x] ((-1 + x^2) Cos[z] Cosh[(455324788 x)/154788525] +
> 2 x Sin[z] Sinh[(455324788 x)/154788525]) +
> 16 (2 x Cos[z] Cosh[(455324788 x)/154788525] + (
> 910649576 x Cosh[(455324788 x)/154788525] Sin[z])/154788525 + (
> 455324788 (-1 + x^2) Cos[z] Sinh[(455324788 x)/154788525])/154788525 +
> 2 Sin[z] Sinh[(455324788 x)/154788525]) Sinh[π x] +
> 16 x Sinh[x y] - (1 +
> x^2)^2 (2 y Cosh[(439301571 x)/74670701] Cosh[x y] + (2 π - y) Cosh[
> 2 π x - x y] + (878603142 Sinh[(439301571 x)/74670701] Sinh[x y])/
> 74670701) + 4 x (-3 + x^2) Sinh[x (2 π + y)] -
> 4 x (1 + x^2) (2 Cosh[(439301571 x)/74670701] Sinh[x y] +
> Sinh[2 π x - x y]),
> 8 x (-1 + x^2) Cosh[x y] +
> x (-3 + x^2)^2 Cosh[
> x (2 π + y)] - (1 +
> x^2)^2 (2 x Cosh[(439301571 x)/74670701] Cosh[x y] -
> x Cosh[2 π x - x y]),
> 16 (-(-1 + x^2) Cosh[(455324788 x)/154788525] Sin[z] +
> 2 x Cos[z] Sinh[(455324788 x)/154788525]) Sinh[π x]}

Then:

```
sol = FindRoot[der == 0, {{x,2.356},{y,0.2},{z,0.802}}, WorkingPrecision->200]
```

> {x -> 2.3565200441011186709479266836966473183706054854973247601995119877870636
> 873150981603534010380380229088216334276519966737386820565998325159972020265215
> 769197743462707338573100057289170401368873924927438,
> y -> 0.2000000753220364175594993792946585546227992037510471951779256130489297
> 718727007710657410091878518650360468748052551939442488448945437837928513056149
> 4115966055206357301610091169316475826091182043682335,
> z -> 0.8026466826422208601123250913908771602390415263594677011546158692691200
> 931397804694020271251338364935933644231667289502052519001113569885205311394434
> 5785707885603139180848781503142732797464512115412727}

Check:

```
der /. sol
```

> {0.*10^-190, 0.*10^-191, 0.*10^-192}

Answer (score 1):

Here are equations with exact values:

```
f := 16 ((-1 + x^2) Cos[z] Cosh[(π - 1/5) x] + 
      2 x Sin[z] Sinh[(π - 1/5) x]) Sinh[π x] + 
   8 (-1 + x^2) Sinh[x y] + (-3 + x^2)^2 Sinh[x (2 π + y)] - 
   (1 + x^2)^2 (2 Cosh[2 (π - 1/5) x] Sinh[x y] + Sinh[2 π x - x y]);
der = D[f, {{x, y, z}}];

der == {0, 0, 0}
```

System of equations `der == {0, 0, 0}` has the following roots over $\mathbb{R}$:

$\{x, y, z\}=\{0,k_1,2 k_2 \pi\}$

$\{x, y, z\}=\{\pm 2.8448343088, 0.8102330214, 3.8176390865 + 2 k \pi\}$

$\{x, y, z\}=\{\pm 0.4832801868, -6.3281385527, 2.2986319740 + 2 k \pi\}$

$\{x, y, z\}=\{\pm 1.1070908912, 1.8252125391, 1.4689358773 + 2 k \pi\}$

$\{x, y, z\}=\{\pm 2.0949603042, 0.1045460795, 0.8907008338 + 2 k \pi\}$

$\{x, y, z\}=\{\pm 2.3565200441, 0.2000000753, 0.8026466826 + 2 k \pi\}$

$k_1,k_2,k \in \mathbb{Z}$

I found these roots analytically, hopefully they are all.

There might be roots over $\mathbb{C}$ as well, I do not have time for that.

In these plots we can see `x` coordinates of roots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ContourPlot3D` shows ( see @flinty 's comment) you, that there doesn't exist a pointwise solution near `{ 2.356 , 0.2 , 0.802 }`

```
f[x_, y_, z_] :=16 ((-1 + x^2) Cos[z] Cosh[2.941592653589793` x] + 
 2 x Sin[z] Sinh[2.941592653589793` x]) Sinh[\[Pi] x] +8 (-1 + x^2) Sinh[x y] + (-3 + x^2)^2 Sinh[x (2 \[Pi] + y)] - (1 + x^2)^2 (2 Cosh[5.883185307179586` x] Sinh[x y] +Sinh[2 \[Pi] x - x y])

Show[{ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, 2, 3}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}],
Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[{ 2.356 , 0.2 , 0.802 }]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: _there doesn't exist a pointwise solution_ ... don't you mean there _does_ exist a solution? If you use more and more PlotPoints then those two contours get closer until they touch at a point.

Comment: @flinty Thanks. I wanted to mention that his answer does not confirm your comment.

Comment: @flinty All the plotted points fullfill `f[x,y,z]==0`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann yes I know. But what proves that _there doesn't exist a pointwise solution_. As far as I can tell, in the limit as PlotPoints goes to infinity and the mesh resolution improves, the two contours should get closer until they touch and meet at a point in very close to the solution in the question.

Comment: @charmin please explain why. Plotting it is not proof because it's also subject to precision and accuracy issues. Consider this question for instance: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/227828/how-can-i-make-sure-that-the-plot-of-this-function-cross-each-other-or-not/227830#227830

Comment: @flinty My point was to show that there is a neighborhood of solutions around this point, not more.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann maybe I misinterpreted _pointwise_, or maybe it's because you wrote _doesn't exist_ in your answer (is this a typo?). Based on Carl's answer it looks like there's a special solution where the two surfaces in your answer join and where the gradient is zero.